# How to move file into virtual server

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi

I have a ESXi server with a Ubuntu server host running. I need to move a script file from my desktop where I manage the host and guest(with vSphere), to a directory on the guest server. Any suggestions on ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd use the same techniques that you would use if the guest was a physical server.  In this case scp via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

scp would be the easiest and fastest solution if you are going to be sharing a lot of files regularly you can set up a SMB shared folder or a NFS, FTP server or whatever... But It's hard to think anything simpler than SCP.

I suppose the trick here would be thinking in your virtual server as a physic one that you can't access directly.

You can use a USB memory connect it to your computer and assign this resource to your server but why not SCP? :P

Answer (score 0):

I actually recently looked into that and I wrote down (or gave links) how to do this for the various ESXi versions. See: https://serverfault.com/a/380925/106102

Basically as mrdenny suggested you just use ssh. It's not always on by default though. And if you copy your ssh key you will have to copy it again after the ESXi server reboots.